# Javascript: Function, Object, new ....a little bit of confusion

Tags: javascript, function, object, return, new-operator

in web I read:

> "Well, Javascript, or better ECMAScript, is an Object Based Language so..
>   Anything that is not a primitive type (undefined, null, number, string, boolean) is an object (or an instance) in JavaScript where an Object is a "bag" of properties and methods..."

and:

> When a function is invoked with “new” keyword then the function is known as constructor function and returns a new instance. In such cases, the value of “this” refers to newly created instance.

Now, my code:

```
function fe(){
    var i;
    var j = 0;
    return j;
};
process.stdout.write("fe --> "); console.log(fe);      // [Function: fe]
process.stdout.write("fe() --> "); console.log(fe());  // 0

var vfe = new fe();
process.stdout.write("vfe --> " + vfe + " - "); console.log(vfe);      [object Object] - fd {}




var fd = function(){
    var i;
    var j = 0;
};
process.stdout.write("fd --> "); console.log(fd);      // [Function: fd]
process.stdout.write("fd() --> "); console.log(fd());  // undefined

var vfd = new fd();
process.stdout.write("vfd --> " + vfd + " - "); console.log(vfd);      [object Object] - fd {}
```

In the first I have value returned and new return an object as the last case: I have an object {} and so I could append properties and methods

in an another case:

```
function fe(){
    var i;
    var j = 0;
    return fe;
};
process.stdout.write("fe --> "); console.log(fe);        // [Function: fe]
process.stdout.write("fe() --> "); console.log(fe());    // [Function: fe]

var vfe = new fe();
process.stdout.write("vfe --> "); console.log(vfe);      // [Function: fe]


var fd = function(){
    var i;
    var j = 0;
    return fd;
};
process.stdout.write("fd --> "); console.log(fd);      // [Function: fd]
process.stdout.write("fd() --> "); console.log(fd());  // [Function: fd]

var vfd = new fd();
process.stdout.write("vfd --> "); console.log(vfd);    // [Function: fd]
```

In this case I have a value or a Function returned that is all but an object....
Now:
id the "Anything that is not a primitive type (undefined, null, number, string, boolean) is an object (or an instance) in JavaScript where an Object is a "bag" of properties and methods..." not so true in all situation?

Another situation is the following:

```
function fe () {
    var pri_var1;
    // private, not accessible from extern
    function pri_fun1(){ return "pri_fun1"; }    
    // private, not accessible from extern
    function pri_fun2(){ return "pri_fun2"; }       
    //static property
    fe.sta_var1 = 0;    //static property ....is never a good idea but...for folks!!!
    //static method
    fe.sta_fun1 = function(){return pri_fun2();}
    //public not heritable
    this.pub_fun1 = function(){return "pub_fun1";}
    //public heritable
    fe.prototype.pub_her_fun1 = function() { return "pub_her_fun1";}
    //return fe;
}

var obj2 = new fe();
console.log("obj2 --> ",obj2);
console.log(obj2.pub_fun1());
console.log(fe.sta_fun1());
```

If I uncomment //return fe; the "node" say:
console.log(obj2.pub_fun1());
                 ^

TypeError: obj2.pub_fun1 is not a function...
If I leave the comment all works as well....

A little bit of confusion about Function and Object in (again):

> "Well, Javascript, or better ECMAScript, is an Object Based Language so.. Anything that is not a primitive type (undefined, null, number, string, boolean) is an object (or an instance) in JavaScript where an Object is a "bag" of properties and methods..."

thanks in advance

Ok...I'll try to be more precise.
I read "Anything that is not a primitive type (undefined, null, number, string, boolean) is an object (or an instance) in JavaScript where an Object is a "bag" of properties and methods..."
Hence a function is an object? Every function?
Take the function:

```
function fe(){
    return 1;
};
```

and the following instructions:

```
console.log(fe);    // [Function: fe]
console.log(fe());  // 1
var vfe = new fe(); 
console.log(vfe);   // fe {}
```

if I read well:
fe is a function that, being non primitive, is an "object" (what kind of object? Maybe somewhat complex type representation [Function: fe] called improperly object in a not OO way?)... but it becomes object in OO way of "bag" {} only after a new (vfe)...., but it can be also be invoked (fe()) and produce a value (1)...or can return itself or by default undefined...
Some functions could not be executed but only "instantiated"? and other function can contains functions which are classical function to execute to get a normal value but not to be instantiated??? 
Very, very strange behaviour...
Can I have an help in terms of naming, design and boundaries about this mess?
thanks again...

Comment: I don't understand.  Could you please describe exactly what your question is?

Comment: `return fe;`  overwrites the constructor function / instance behavior and instead assigns the function itself to `obj2`, regardless of the `new`. Don't return anything and you get an instance that behaves as expected. Even better: learn the new `class` stuff that was added to JavaScript.

Comment: I've voting to close this as off-topic because it is too broad. You seem to have four separate questions here, none of them expressed very clearly.

Comment: "*what about functions*" - they're objects as well (regardless of their kind).

Answer (score 1):

When you call a function as a constructor (i.e. `new func()`), JS takes these steps:

- it creates a new object, let's call it `newObject`
- it calls your function in a special way, so that `this` inside your function becomes `newObject`
- the function runs, and returns a value, let's call it `retVal`
- now JS looks into `retVal`. If it's nothing (that is, `undefined`) or a primitive value, then `retVal` is ignored (thrown away), and the result of whole `new func()` thing will be `newObject`
- if, however, `retVal` is an object, JS does quite the opposite: `newObject` is discarded, and the value of `new func()` will be `retVal`

This explains your results, because in the first case you're returning a primitive (`0`) and in the second case, an object (`fd`, which is a function, and functions are objects).

Illustration:

```js
function returnsPrimitive() {
  this.x = 1
  return 42
}

console.log(returnsPrimitive())
console.log(new returnsPrimitive())


function returnsObject() {
  this.x = 1
  return {foo:1}
}

console.log(returnsObject())
console.log(new returnsObject())
```